# JQuery not changing my radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have described a set of radio buttons in xhtml and am trying to set the programatically with jQuery 2.0.2.  The radio buttons represent a color look up table (LUT) and I would like to set the correct radio button given the current value of the LUT which is given by a variable lut which is text.  Each of the radio buttons has a name LUT and a value which is the same as the lut variable for the given selection.  For example, if I have chosen GRAY as the LUT, then the button to check would have a value 'GRAY' and lut would be a text string 'GRAY'.  I therefore tried checking the radio button with

```
jQuery('input[name=LUT][value=lut]').prop("checked",true);
```

It did not give me any errors in Firebug but it also did not do anything.

The Grey button has the following form

```
<input type="radio" name="LUT" id="GREY" value="GREY" onclick="EnableNonlinear()" />Gray
```

Comment: did u try your jquery selector in firebug's javascript console?

Comment: Your code should work fine. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEtf/) fiddler demo to see if I'm missing something

Comment: I tried jQuery('input[name=LUT][value=lut]').prop("checked",true); on the Firebug console.  It ran without errors but did not set the gray button.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `lut` is a variable, but your jQuery selector is just a string. Try this

```
jQuery('input[name=LUT][value=' + lut + ']').prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

your selector includes `value=lut`but your HTML `value=GREY`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be your selector, you're using `value=lut` when it should be `value=GREY`.

`jQuery` won't raise an error, it'll only return an empty `jQuery` object, if you wan't to check this, you can print the following:

```
//You can use alert if you want
console.log(jQuery('input[name=LUT][value=lut]').length);  //Should be 0

console.log(jQuery('input[name=LUT][value=GREY]').length); // >= 1
```

I suggest that if you have an `id` on the element, you use that to select it, because it'll be faster, and you can't make the mistake of selecting another one:

```
jQuery('#GREY').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wanted the select to be more generic rather than having to use a switch statement.